# Share image/video/album from friend via Facebook Graph API

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I'm tackling a problem relating to sharing on facebook, please help me do it.
In my app, a list of video, photo posted by my friends (facebook) appear and I want to add a share button for that. How can I do that?
I can implement a posting method for external picture (another website, not facebook) but only thumbnail will appear, and text doesn't appear like sharing on web browser (big picture, gray vertical line on the left).

the attached image is to represent for sharing post that I want.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after searching around and testing, I found the solution:
- use grapth api: me/feed
- possible parameters: message and link; link points to the page containing photo/video u want to share while message is your custom message.